# Why does my number guessing game keep looping even after the right guess is made?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, project

The program is a Number guessing Game. The program doesn't stop executing after all 5 guesses are executed. What is the bug in the code?

```
#importing modules
import random

#ASCII Art Logo
logo="""
█▀▀▀ █──█ █▀▀ █▀▀ █▀▀ 　 ▀▀█▀▀ █──█ █▀▀ 　 █▀▀▄ █──█ █▀▄▀█ █▀▀▄ █▀▀ █▀▀█ 
█─▀█ █──█ █▀▀ ▀▀█ ▀▀█ 　 ──█── █▀▀█ █▀▀ 　 █──█ █──█ █─▀─█ █▀▀▄ █▀▀ █▄▄▀ 
▀▀▀▀ ─▀▀▀ ▀▀▀ ▀▀▀ ▀▀▀ 　 ──▀── ▀──▀ ▀▀▀ 　 ▀──▀ ─▀▀▀ ▀───▀ ▀▀▀─ ▀▀▀ ▀─▀▀"""
print(logo)
print("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!")
choices_list=[]
for i in range (0,100):
  choices_list.append(i+1)
chosen_number=random.choices(choices_list)[0]
print(chosen_number)
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. \n")
game_level=input("Choose a difficulty. Type 'easy' or 'hard'.").lower()
if game_level=='easy':
  attempts=10
elif game_level=='hard':
  attempts=5

#function that enables player to make a guess
def user_choice(attempts):
  print(f"You have {attempts} attempts left to guess the number.")
  choice=int(input("Make a guess: "))
  if choice<chosen_number:
    print("Too Low")
    attempts-=1
    while attempts>0:
      user_choice(attempts)
  elif choice>chosen_number:
    print("Too High.")
    attempts-=1
    while attempts>0:
      user_choice(attempts)
  elif choice==chosen_number:
    print("Congratulations! You made the right guess!")
  
  
    

user_choice(attempts)
```

I tried to insert break statements but they caused syntax errors.

Comment: Don't use recursion when you want to use a loop. See your code in action at http://pythontutor.com, that should clarify what's happening.

Comment: The call `user_choice(attempts)` doesn't (and cannot) change the caller's `attempts`.

Comment: As a side note, the whole beginning is just `chosen_number = random.randint(1, 100)`. You should always have a deep look at the documentation of modules you use. See  https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found that you could just change the while to if for both of the whiles and it will run just fine. so the code would be:

```
#importing modules
import random

#ASCII Art Logo
logo="""
█▀▀▀ █──█ █▀▀ █▀▀ █▀▀ 　 ▀▀█▀▀ █──█ █▀▀ 　 █▀▀▄ █──█ █▀▄▀█ █▀▀▄ █▀▀ █▀▀█ 
█─▀█ █──█ █▀▀ ▀▀█ ▀▀█ 　 ──█── █▀▀█ █▀▀ 　 █──█ █──█ █─▀─█ █▀▀▄ █▀▀ █▄▄▀ 
▀▀▀▀ ─▀▀▀ ▀▀▀ ▀▀▀ ▀▀▀ 　 ──▀── ▀──▀ ▀▀▀ 　 ▀──▀ ─▀▀▀ ▀───▀ ▀▀▀─ ▀▀▀ ▀─▀▀"""
print(logo)
print("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!")
choices_list=[]
for i in range (0,100):
  choices_list.append(i+1)
chosen_number=random.choices(choices_list)[0]
print(chosen_number)
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. \n")
game_level=input("Choose a difficulty. Type 'easy' or 'hard'.").lower()
if game_level=='easy':
  attempts=10
elif game_level=='hard':
  attempts=5

#function that enables player to make a guess
def user_choice(attempts):
  print(f"You have {attempts} attempts left to guess the number.")
  choice=int(input("Make a guess: "))
  if choice<chosen_number:
    print("Too Low")
    attempts-=1
    if attempts>0:
      user_choice(attempts)
  elif choice>chosen_number:
    print("Too High.")
    attempts-=1
    if attempts>0:
      user_choice(attempts)
  elif choice==chosen_number:
    print("Congratulations! You made the right guess!")
  
  
    

user_choice(attempts)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want your while loop outside the if logic:

Some thing like this:

```
def user_choice(attempts):
  while attempts>0:
    print(f"You have {attempts} attempts left to guess the number.")
    choice=int(input("Make a guess: "))
    if choice<chosen_number:
      print("Too Low")
      attempts-=1
    elif choice>chosen_number:
      print("Too High.")
      attempts-=1
    elif choice==chosen_number:
      print("Congratulations! You made the right guess!")
      break
  else:
    print("You've run out of guesses, you lose.")
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `user_attempts` becomes zero, the function `user_choice` ends. However, because you're calling them recursively, when `user_choice` ends, it will fall back to the previous function call in your recursion, redefining your attempts value. In Python, I recommend avoiding recursion if it's possible, because...

- The recursion limit is 1000
- Each time you invoke a new recursion, Python allocates more memory.

See Bendik's answer for a good approach to doing this.